# Get tabs of Tabview in Javascript

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a tabview on page and add tabs with javascript dynamically. At the same time add the opened tab names to a list(lstOpenedPages). But close a tab, I can't get name of this tab which is closed for delete from the list. Now I want to read remain tabs of tabview because I can find which tab is closed from the list (lstOpenedPages).

How to I get remain tabs of tabview in Javascript?

xhtml code

```
<p:tabView id="tw" widgetVar="tw">  
   <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{MenuBean.onTabClose}"/>
</p:tabView>

<p:menuitem value="#{itemMenu.menuAck}" 
            action="#{MenuBean.OpenPage(itemMenu.pageName)}" 
            ajax="true"
            oncomplete="handleTabViewEvent(args);" 
/>

<script type="text/javascript">
      function handleTabViewEvent(args) {
          alert('Add tab here..');
       }
</script>
```

bean

```
public void OpenPage(String pageName) {
    lstOpenedPages.add(pageName);
}

public void onTabClose(TabCloseEvent event) {  
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    TabView tw = (TabView)context.getViewRoot().findComponent("centerForm:tw");
    String s = "I must delete tab here from lstOpenedPages which closed. But event does not give me tab information. It is always null. So I must be delete from javascript";
}
```

Comment: Why exactly are you adding them with JS instead of with JSF? Do you realize that this way the HTML DOM state is unknown to JSF?

Comment: My friend I edited my question more clearly. thanks for your care.